# Forcing an application to use gtk 3 instead of gtk 2

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Is there anyway to force an application to use gtk3+ instead of gtk2+ ?

Answer (score 6):

No: the application needs to be ported to GTK3. This means adapting the application's source code to the new GTK API and linking against the new libraries.

If you'd like to see your favorite application ported to GTK3, you should get in touch with its developers.